# Visual plugin loaded twice

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello everybody,

I'm having an issue with a visual plugin. Similarly to *Illuminatur* in [this thread](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/13317/questions-about-the-appropriate-dealing-with-visualplugin/), the plugin I'm using is loaded twice.
More precisely, it's loaded twice only when the model of the robot I'm using is loaded in addition to the model that uses the plugin.

The plugin I'm referring to is [here](https://github.com/robotology/gazebo-yarp-plugins/tree/master/plugins/videotexture), it's a plugin to put texture on an object via YARP.

The robot I'm simulating is the iCub ([sdf files here](https://github.com/robotology/icub-gazebo))

Is that a known/desired behavior? Is there a simple way to prevent Gazebo from loading it twice?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/15939/visual-plugin-loaded-twice/) by [MSI](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3155/msi/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-04-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

When you launch a gazebo world that has a camera sensor, two rendering scenes are actually created (server + client). So the visual plugin is loaded twice because it's loaded once on the server (for the camera sensor) and another time on the client (for the main UI window).

---

Originally posted by [iche033](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/58/iche033/) with karma: 1018 on 2017-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MSI](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3155/msi/) on 2017-05-11**:
Hello Iche,
Thank you very much for your answer. I would upvote if I could. I will now contact the people who developed that plugin!